# Build recursion in parallel?

Tags: parallelization, recursion

*Problem*

Let's define a simple recursion.

```
f[1] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1]*n;
```

If I evaluate f in parallel

```
ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 10}];
```

and then query f

```
?f
Global`f
f[1]=1
f[n_]:=f[n]=f[n-1] n
```

*Question*

How can I tell the sub kernels to build up the recursion, so that

```
?f

Global`f

f[1]=1
....
f[10]=3628800

f[n_]:=f[n]=f[n-1] n
```

Thanks !

PS: of course the actual function is not that trivial.

Comment: Does `SetSharedFunction[f]` do what you want?

Comment: Indeed, thank you! Should I remove my question?

Comment: On the other hand it does not re-export to the different kernels the known definitions. `Table[f[i], {i, 5000}]; // Timing`
(* {0.005126,Null} *)
`ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 5000}]; // Timing`
(* {6.69067,Null} *)

Comment: Indeed. I can remember that I once ran into that problem but I couldn't find a solution to distribute `DownValues` from the subkernels. Maybe you can formulate your question more generally (with a different title?), so you get more attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sebhofer provides a partial answer via the command

```
SetSharedFunction[f]
```

which collects to the master kernel the accumulated downvalues. On the other hand, the slave kernels seem unaware of these.

Indeed

```
ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 5000}]; 
Table[f[i], {i, 5000}]; // Timing
```

(* {0.005126,Null} *)

which suggests the master kernel does remember the previous definitions.
On the other hand,

```
ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 5000}]; // Timing
```

(* {6.69067,Null} *)

still takes quite some time.

Comment: The reason the second invocation takes a while has changed, though--`f` exists only in the master kernel and is fetched using a callback every time it's referenced in one of the slaves. This is still basically a serial operation, but now it involves a lot of communication overhead. Unfortunately it isn't easy to do what you want given the way the ``Parallel` `` package works. I thought you could perhaps try something like `f[n_]:=g[n]=f[n-1] n` with `SetSharedFunction[g]; DistributeDefinitions[f]`, but this doesn't seem to work... sorry, no time for a more considered response!