# Map efficiently over duplicates in list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am interested in mapping a function, `f` over a (long) list which contains duplicates.
Since this function takes a while to evaluate I would like to make use of this duplication to speed up the mapping.

***Attempt***

Let us say my list is

```
list = {a, a, b, a, c, b}
```

my purpose is to map `f` over `list` efficiently.
I have defined a function

```
MapDuplicate[f_, list_] := Module[{ff, list1, ulist},
list1 = ff /@ list; (* ff is dummy f *) 
ulist = Union[list]; (* the reduced list *)
rr = Dispatch[Thread[(ff /@ ulist) -> (f /@ ulist)]];
list1 /. rr]
```

which does the trick,

```
MapDuplicate[f1, list]

(* {f1(a),f1(a),f1(b),f1(a),f1(c),f1(b)} *)
```

but I strongly suspect there is a more elegant (using `Ordering`? `SparseArray`?) of doing this.

***Question***

> Any idea on how to do this more efficiently (e.g. without duplicating the list)
>   My apologies in advance if the answer turns out to be trivial.

Comment: Considered memoization? I.e., `f[x_]:=f[x]= your definition` used with `Map`: `f/@list`

Comment: No I had not! I tend to think of memorization as attached to the function rather than to lists. I guess it would do the trick.

Comment: Though if I want to parallelize the mapping I suspect it won't work cf http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9186/build-recursion-in-parallel

Comment: Keep in mind that both memoization or other hash-based approaches (rules, `Dispatch`, etc) may actually make things  *slower* for numerical lists when your function is compilable, since `Map` auto-compiles and switching to memoization etc you will lose that advantage (not to detract from the suggestions to use memoization etc, since those are the right things to do generically).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
dispatchTable = Dispatch[ # -> g[#] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[list]]
(* {a -> g[a], b -> g[b], c -> g[c]}  *)
list/.dispatchTable
(* {g[a], g[a], g[b], g[a], g[c], g[b]} *)
```

or memoization:

```
f[x_]:=f[x]= 3 x (* say *)
```

with `Map`

```
f/@list
(*  {3 a, 3 a, 3 b, 3 a, 3 c, 3 b} *)
```

or with `ParallelMap`:

```
ParallelMap[f, list]
```

Comment: it seems to me the last option, `ParallelMap` will not be as efficient as it should be because sub-kernels will not know about what other kernels have already memorized.

Comment: @chris, good point. I have not done any testing with `ParallelMap`; and just saw your related question. Parallelization versus memoization (in case the choice is one of either/or) would make a great question: pros/cons, trade-offs involved etc.

Comment: I suggest modifying your answer to `dispatchTable =Dispatch[ # -> g[#] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[list]]` which will makes it more efficient if the dispatch table is long

Comment: @chris, another great point. I actually did mean to use `Dispatch`:)

Comment: first option (dispatch) seems about 30 % faster.